# Magento backup functionality is deprecated as of 2.1.16, 2.2.7, and 2.3.0?

Tags: backup

I was happily reading the documeent below enjoying the fact that these backup commands for media, db and code existed

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html

But then I read

`Deprecation Notice Magento backup functionality is deprecated as of 2.1.16, 2.2.7, and 2.3.0. We recommend investigating additional backup technologies and binary backup tools (such as Percona XtraBackup).`

So does this really mean the commands `bin/magento setup:backup` and `bin/magento info:backups:list` and `bin/magento setup:rollback` will stop working?

So is this true? (or am I reading this wrong)

And maybe then why?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation):

In several fields, deprecation is the discouragement of use of some terminology, feature, design, or practice, typically because it has been superseded or is no longer considered efficient or safe, without completely removing it or prohibiting its use. It can also imply that a feature, design, or practice will be removed or discontinued entirely in the future

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. The commands would not be working. When you navigate to System->Backups in the backend you will find the message

> Backup functionality is currently disabled. Please use other means for
>   backups

When you execute the command in CLI you will find the message

> Enabling maintenance mode
>
> DB backup is starting...
>
> Backup functionality is disabled
>
> Disabling maintenance mode

You can enable backup by navigating to `System->Advanced->Backup Settings`
[image]

Once you enable it you will find the `System->Backup` functionality

[image]

It has been deprecated as a result of few bugs with the backup functionality as such maintenance flag is not deleted after the backup and so on.

Comment: Also `php bin/magento config:set system/backup/functionality_enabled 1` would enable it. But reading the above means: dont use it?

Comment: You can use it too where you are setting the configuration value directly without a user interface in core_config table. We are not aware of all the issues with backup functionality but there are many tickets open in git.